# Get Repeater data with foreach it always returns first item

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a Repeater in my page and after databinding, I have to click on a button to postback in page, and I need to do a foreach in all data from my Repeater. In true I have to get each item inside foreach statment as example.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem itemEquipment in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            //to get the dropdown of each line
            DropDownList yourDropDown = (DropDownList)itemEquipment.FindControl("DropDownListadet");

            //to get the selected value of your dropdownlist
            string value = yourDropDown.SelectedValue;
        }
```

i try this example but it always returns first item how can ı solve this

aspx page

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
       
        <ItemTemplate>
             
            <div id='<%# Eval("UrunID")+"_" %>' class="row">
               
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="box box-warning  collapsed-box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" class="img-circle" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("UrunResim_Path") %>' Width="80px" runat="server" />
                            <h1 class="box-title">&#160; &#160;&#160; <%# Eval("UrunADI") %></h1>

                            <div class=" box-tools   pull-right">
                                <button class=" btn btn-box-tool" style="width: 60px; height: 60px" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-tools -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                        <div  class="box-body">
                             
                            <asp:Label ID="Labelfiyat" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("UrunFiyat") %>' CssClass="resimlbl"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Labelurunıd" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("UrunID") %>' CssClass="resimlbl"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Labelkar" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("UrunKar_Yuzde") %>' CssClass="resimlbl"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Labeladı" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("UrunADI") %>' CssClass="resimlbl"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelID" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Eval("UrunID") %>' CssClass="resimlbl"></asp:Label>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListadet" enableEventValidation="False"  AutoPostBack="false" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem  Value="0">-- ADET SEÇ --</asp:ListItem>
                                   
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div id="MFDİV" runat="server" class="form-group">

                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListmf" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- MF SEÇ --</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group" style="width: 200px;">
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" enableEventValidation="False" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-primary" OnCommand="ButtonComand" Text="EKLE" />

                            </div>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_gdogru" Visible="false" runat="server">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                        <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>Eklendi!</h4>
                                        Başarıyla Eklendi...
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_gyanlis" Visible="false" runat="server">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                        <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i>Hata!</h4>
                                        Bir Sorun Çıktı Boşlukları Doldurun Lütfen...
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box -->
                </div>
                  
            </div>
            <%--repeater bitiş--%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

this is default value
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq3wu.jpg

and ı select random number

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPIdP.jpg

and click this button

```
 protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem itemEquipment in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            //to get the dropdown of each line
            DropDownList yourDropDown = (DropDownList)itemEquipment.FindControl("DropDownListadet");

            //to get the selected value of your dropdownlist
            string value = yourDropDown.SelectedValue;
        }

        foreach (RepeaterItem itemEquipment in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            //to get the dropdown of each line
            DropDownList yourDropDown = (DropDownList)itemEquipment.FindControl("DropDownListadet");

            //to get the selected value of your dropdownlist
            string value = yourDropDown.SelectedValue;
        }


        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            RepeaterItem item = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
            if (ri.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || ri.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                Panel pnl = ri.FindControl("pnl_gdogru") as Panel;

                DropDownList ddladet = ri.FindControl("DropDownListadet") as DropDownList;
                DropDownList ddlmf = ri.FindControl("DropDownListmf") as DropDownList;
                Label lblfiyat = ri.FindControl("Labelfiyat") as Label;
                DropDownList yourDropDown = (DropDownList)ri.FindControl("DropDownListadet");
                Label ıd = ri.FindControl("LabelID") as Label;



                Label Labelkar = ri.FindControl("Labelkar") as Label;
                Label Labeladı = ri.FindControl("Labeladı") as Label;
                Label LabelID = ri.FindControl("LabelID") as Label;
                string a = ıd.Text;
                string b = ddladet.SelectedItem.Text;
                string c = ddlmf.SelectedItem.Text;
                string d = ddladet.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                
                string f = yourDropDown.SelectedIndex.ToString();

                double birimfiyat = ((Convert.ToDouble(lblfiyat.Text)) / ((Convert.ToDouble(Labelkar.Text) / 100) + 1)) * (Convert.ToDouble(ddladet.SelectedValue)) / (Convert.ToDouble(ddlmf.SelectedValue) + Convert.ToDouble(ddladet.SelectedValue));
                birimfiyat = Math.Round(birimfiyat, 3);

                if (ddladet.SelectedItem.Text != "-- ADET SEÇ --")
                {


                    SqlC.con.Open();
                    SqlC.com.CommandText = "use kasa insert into SiparişTemP3( tip, UrunAdıID, UrunADI, Adet, MalfazlasıAdet, Toplam, BirimFiyat, SatışFiyat, KullanıcıID,EczaneID) values( '0',  " + LabelID.Text + "   , '" + Labeladı.Text + "', '" + ddladet.SelectedValue.ToString() + "', '" + ddlmf.SelectedValue.ToString() + "', '" + (Convert.ToInt32(ddladet.SelectedValue) + Convert.ToInt32(ddlmf.SelectedValue) + "', " + birimfiyat.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + ", " + lblfiyat.Text.Replace(",", ".") + ", '" + KullanıcıID() + "','" + EczaneID + "')");
                    SqlC.com.Connection = SqlC.con;
                    SqlC.com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlC.con.Close();


                }
            }



        }

        SqlC.con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd12 = new SqlCommand("use kasa select SiparisID,EczaneID, UrunADI, Adet, MalfazlasıAdet,Toplam,BirimFiyat,SatışFiyat from SiparişTemP3 where KullanıcıID = '" + KullanıcıID() + "'");
        cmd12.Connection = SqlC.con;
        SqlDataAdapter sda21 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd12);
        DataTable dt112 = new DataTable();
        sda21.Fill(dt112);
        Repeater2.DataSource = dt112;
        Repeater2.DataBind();
        SqlC.con.Close();


    }
```

and the dropdownadet returns the default value

like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDWaX.jpg

Comment: It might be `(DropDownList)itemEquipment.FindControl("...");`, since you are iterating over `itemEquipment`, not `item`.

Comment: I did not understand what to do but thx

Comment: In your foreach, you are iteration over a collection. For each loop, you have a variable named `itemEquipment`. Inside your loop, you are not using it, so i guessed(!), that you need to use `itemEquipment`. In other words: it is not clear from your snippet, what `item` is. Again, other words: why do you iterate, but do not use `itemEquipment`?
Hope i could explain it better this time.

Comment: nilsK is saying to change `(DropDownList)item.FindControl` to `(DropDownList)itemEquipment.FindControl` ...can you see the difference? `itemEquipment` represents the specific repeater item within the repeater, so you need to use that to get the current row each time. It's unclear what, in your code, is represented by `item`.

Comment: sory my bad,  ı write wrong example  but its still returns first value

Comment: Just to clearify: whay exaclty do you mean by 'first item'? Is it `yourDropDown` or `SelectedValue`?

Comment: I detailed a little more thx for help

Comment: What are you doing with `value`  in your first two foreach blocks? You're shoving a value into a variable, then not using that variable. Presumably you need to *do something* with that variable.

Comment: first two foreach blocks is just  to try. I try to use variable but still the dropdownlist returns the first value